# Browser Session Exists when moved from App

Tags: android-espresso, android-uiautomator

Mobile application that i work,will enter url and it will navigate to mobile browser and have to provide credentials.Post credentials validated token will be sent to app that is initiated.
While automation it using Espresso and UIautomator.
While running,browser stores existing session and sends token automatically.Require to exit session of browser and login everytime while running script

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question to make it a bit clearer? Thanks

Comment: Use Case:When i open app and enter account url,it will redirect to browser to enter credentials.Post login validation in browser,app will open as logged in user.In espresso automation when i enter account url,it navigates to browser and using uiautomator able to provide login details and it navigates to app.When i re-run again,as browser session not cleared,it won't land in login page as already session present.Here when app redirects to browser,wants to clear existing browser session if any.

Comment: does the answer below help you to figure out the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing your tests, you have to delete all the data related to the browser you're using. This can be achieved by using the following adb command:

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.chrome
```

(you can replace the package id with the browser you're using)
or by using ui-automator and provide the same command:

```
mDevice.executeShellCommand("pm clear com.android.chrome")
```

where `mDevice` is an instance of [UiDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiDevice) object.

The only drawback of this approach is that, being a fresh start, most likely the browser will ask you some questions like usage statistics and turning on sync... actions that can be automated quite easily using ui-automator.